# Is the following set is the power of the continuum?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a set:

$A=\{\langle x,y\rangle :x\in \mathbb{R}, y\in \mathbb{R}:x^2=y\}$

I must prove that $A$ is Continuum. So I have to show that there is a bijection - OK. But how I can that write?

I drew a graph square function and I think, that this bijection be projection on the axis OX. But I'm not sure.

Could somebody help me?

Comment: You have the correct bijection $x\in\mathbb{R}\to (x,x^2)\in A$ with inverse $(x,x^2)\in A\to x\in\mathbb{R}.$

Answer (score 0):

I show injection:

$f(x)=f(x) \Rightarrow x=y\\
(x,x^2)=(y,y^2)\Rightarrow x=y, x^2=y^2\Rightarrow x=y$

Therefore, there is injective

And I want show surjection:
$\forall_{(x,y)\in A} \exists_{z\in\mathbb{R}} f(z)=(x,y)$

So, $(z,z^2)=(x,y)$.

How is next step?

Comment: This must not be an answer. You can edit your question showing your progress or improving the question.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I'm new in this forum

Comment: To show surjectivity, note that any element of $A$ is of the form $(x,x^2).$ Is not $f(x)=(x,x^2)?$ So, $f$ is surjective. Thus, if $f$ is injective and surjective then it is bijective. So, you are done.